# Couple of questions on Bernard Bolzano's philosophy of state

Tags: political-philosophy, state, socialism

I read a summary of Bolzano's political views and his philosophy of the "best" state, and I have 3 questions -

A) was Bolzano heavily influenced by the USA? His line of thought for some of his ideas seems very similar in mind to (at least the original) USA thought.

B) what was (if any) the critic of Bolzano's thought? Besides capitalism of course, as his ideas are obviously against capitalism.

C) is there any contemporary political thinker that follows Bolzano's thoughts?